# Raspberry Pi Zero W Honeypot (similar to Wireless AP)

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi, wireless

**I want to access a server on the Raspberry Pi Zero via WiFi.**

[YouTube Video describing the Problem](https://youtu.be/abuUTBM6LHE)

I am following the tutorial on this [Blog](https://andrewmichaelsmith.com/2013/08/raspberry-pi-wi-fi-honeypot/) for the Raspberry Pi .

Accessing the server with another laptop doesn't work. It says that it is not connected.

**When I run** on the Raspi

```
sudo cat /var/log/dnsmasq.log
```

I get at the end this error:

```
May 9 09:59:28 dnsmasq-dhcp[513]: no address range available for DHCP request via wlan0
```

But I am not sure if this has to do anything with the problem at all.

**How can I make the Raspi Zero W http-Server (the http server is a server on the raspi) connectable over WiFi?**

**Here are the relevant parts of the files.**

File: /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface wlan0 inet static
address 10.0.0.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 255.0.0.0
pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.rules
```

File: /etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
#...
#at the end of the file
log-facility=/var/log/dnsmasq.log
address=/#/10.0.0.1
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=10.0.0.10,10.0.0.250,12h
no-resolv
log-queries
```

File: /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

```
option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;
send host-name = gethostname(); 
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
        domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
        dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.domain-search,
        netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
        rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers;
```

File: /etc/dhcpcd.conf

```
# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses instead of hardware based ones
slaac private

# A hook script is provided to lookup the hostname if not set by the DHCP
# server, but it should not be run by default.
nohook lookup-hostname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read the blog and i successfully implemented the server following all the steps.
It is possible that you have misconfigured something. My bets are on the `/etc/network/interfaces` file or on the `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`.
Also, check if you don't have another dhcp server on. Maybe the internal `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` is overwritting your ip pool.
Post the relevant part of all those files to see if there is any error.

Comment: I didn't find the "/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf" so I posted the "/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf" and "/etc/dhcpcd.conf",

Did you use the Raspi Zero W? Because this one doesn't have an Ethernet port eth0.

How can you find out if you have another dhcp server running?

Comment: Im using a raspberry pi 2 B which has a eth0 interface. If you don't have it, try removing the eth0 part on your etc/network/interfaces file. I have also another extra line: allow-hotplug wlan0 in that file. To check if you have some type of dhcp server running, try "ps aux | grep dhcp" and see if it returns something suspicius. Finally, ensure that your wlan interface is up.

Comment: removed the eth0,

added at the top in "etc/network/interfaces",

allow-hotplug wlan0,
It now works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution, plug in a HDMI monitor and keyboard and use the desktop network GUI to set up the Wifi (click on the WiFi logo, top right).

A longer winded option would be to use one of the hundreds of how to articles out there, for Raspberry Pis (regardless of Pi zero to Pi3 they are the same).
A quick Google search found this: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-3-network-setup/setting-up-wifi-with-occidentalis

Or even (for those with shorter attention spans): https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=raspberry+pi+configure+wifi&oq=raspberry+pi+configure+wifi&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6863j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=raspberry+pi+configure+wifi&tbm=vid

Good luck and don't be afraid to Google for these things.

Comment: thank you for this answer. I am sorry, maybe I described the question the wrong way. The http server is on the raspi zero w and I want to connect a mobile device to the raspi's server.

Answer (score 0):

If you run ifconfig -a, does your wlan0 interface have the proper IP address, 10.0.0.1? Mine did not. In /etc/network/interfaces I added the line

allow-hotplug wlan0

above the iface wlan0 line. That seemed to fix the address problem and the same error, "no address range available for DHCP request via wlan0" you are getting.

You have a problem with web pages then as nginx looks for pages in /var/www/html.
Use this line ...

```
sudo echo "<h1>hello<h1>" > /var/www/html/index.html
```

Note removal of "!" and different destination folder

I had the exact same problems you had and this got mine working for the most part.